# Newbie looking for BigQuery Standard SQL tutorial, examples, books,

Tags: google-bigquery

I have used SQL a fair amount for several years. I just started a project that use Google Firebase and BigQuery to explore what users are doing on our website.

The raw data in BigQuery (the Firebase events) are very complicated.

It appears BigQuery is using SQL 2011. I am not sure how that is different from SQL-99 or SQL-2009. I have not found a good over view or tutorial.

Some of the challenges I am struggling with include grouping events in to session and identifying groups with certain characteristics

I wonder if instead of using `GROUP BY`  I need to learn how windowing works.

Any suggestions for getting up the learning curve faster would be greatly appreciated.

Andy

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that the most efficient schema is not multiple flat tables with relations anymore. Instead it is having nested data in one big table.

I call them subtables, but they're really just arrays containing structs. Which may contain arrays which contain structs. Which may ... etc.

The most important thing to learn is how to work with these arrays. There are basically two use cases:

- you need a field from a subtable to be a dimension in your result: you have to flatten the table using cross join. Cross joining a subtable with its parent is a weird concept, but works pretty fine.
- you want some aggregated information from a subtable: use a subquery on the array and get it

Both concepts can be learned by working on all the exercises here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

But GCP also has some courses on coursera covering BigQuery. I'm not sure how much they go in depth, though.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the question BigQuery is compliant with the SQL 2011 [[1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/)].

In BigQuery [analytic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts) or [aggregate analytic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts#aggregate-analytic-functions) are used for windowing.

For reference you can have a look at official BigQuery standard SQL [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) and for deeper understanding of BigQuery you can have a look at [Google BigQuery Analytics](https://books.google.es/books/about/Google_BigQuery_Analytics.html?id=_2KRAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) book.